# Convert String to Decimal - leave digits

Tags: c#

I've got a form which allows a user to enter a price, for example, `10.00`.

However as the form is purley text a user could enter `$10.00` or `10.00 for book`. 
I cannot change the UI, this has to be done under the hood. 
So basically what ever the use types I just want a decimal result.

I started to do this

```
public decimal FilterPrice(dynamic price) {
    string convertPrice=price.ToString();

    var filterNumber=
        from letter in convertPrice
        where char.IsDigit(letter)
        select letter;

    return something;
}
```

However this will strip out `.`.  Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: *Why* can't this be done in the UI? You should limit your input at the earliest possible time, not let the user enter whatever they want and then try to figure out what they meant. What if I used your application and typed in "10.00 foo 11 bar 1.1.10baz"?

Comment: Honestly I would trim, remove $ sign and if it's still not valid I would throw an exception.

Comment: Yeah by allowing extra input it creates more error handling code for you. If you can filter a bulk prior it will run smoother and take less time.

Comment: If you are going to allow any free-form text, you are going to have to do some parsing, either character by character, or using RegEx.  In either case, you will have to come up with whatever rule you want to decide something is "valid."  Not only text, but if this is a regionalized app, you'll also have to account for different currency symbols, decimal separators, etc.  It could get a little messy.

Comment: This absolutely must be a UI change. "10.00 for a book" should be separated into two separate fields -- cost (10.00) and reason ("for a book"). You're going to run into all kinds of problems like this otherwise.

Comment: Guys, thank you for the input and help, but its complicated and I dont have access to the front end, hence I stated "I cannot change the UI" office politics im afraid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve it with a simple Regex.

```
    public bool TryGetPreisAsDecimal(string price, out decimal convertedPrice)
    { 
        Match match = Regex.Match(price,@"\d+(\.\d{1,2})?");

        if (match != null)
        {
            convertedPrice = decimal.Parse(match.Value);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            convertedPrice = 0.0m;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would make this a TryGet method, simply because a user entered value of "$0.00 per book" cannot be differentiated from "$ per book"

Comment: A method named `TryXxx` would returns `bool` value conventionally.

Comment: Just to throw in my two cents - this regex wouldn't let me throw in my ".02".  It would let me throw in my "0.02", though, so that's not too bad.